# Simple PHP string replace?

Tags: php

I have this code:

```
$abc = ' Hello "Guys" , Goodmorning';
```

I want to replace every occurrence of `"` (double quotes) by `$^` so that string becomes

```
'Hello $^Guys$^ , Goodmorning'
```

I am new to PHP; in Java we can do this very easily by calling the string class `replaceAll` function, but how do I do it in PHP? I can't find the easy way on Google without using regular expressions.

What is some syntax with or without the use of regular expressions?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Have a look at [`str_replace`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

```
$abc = ' Hello "Guys" , Goodmorning';
$abc = str_replace('"', '$^', $abc);
```

Answer (score 8):

```
str_replace('"','$^',$abc);
```

Should work for you.

Answer (score 4):

```
$abc = ' Hello "Guys" , Goodmorning';

$new_string = str_replace("\"", '$^', $abc);
echo $new_string;
```

output:

> Hello $^Guys$^ , Goodmorning

Answer (score 3):

```
preg_replace('/"/', '$^', $abc);
```

Answer (score 1):

[Searching the manual](http://php.net/manual-lookup.php?pattern=string_replace&lang=en) would have brought you to this: http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

```
str_replace('"', '$^', $abc);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`str_replace`](http://de3.php.net/manual/de/function.str-replace.php):

```
$abc = ' Hello "Guys" , Goodmorning';
echo str_replace('"','$^',$abc);
```

Answer (score 0):

String replace function is used to replace string. Your syntax is wrong. You have to use [php string function](https://technosmarter.com/php/PHP-String-Functions.html) like below example. First of all, think about first and two values and replace in third. Let's have a look.

```
<?php
echo str_replace("Hello", "HI", "Hello Jack "); 
?>
```

It produces the output.

```
HI Jack.
```

You can create an HTML form and change on button only.

```
<form> 
input box 1 
input box 2 
input box 3 
button 

</form>
```

Another

```
 str_replace('"','$^',$var);
```