# Removing &nbsp; from a json file in php

Tags: php, json

I have a JSON file that I'm requesting from a remote URL. I noticed that the resulting file has `&nbsp;` characters within it. What would be the best way to remove all of them and replace them with a regular space.

I tried html_entity_decode but it ended up breaking the json file. Also, string replace didn't remove them.

Comment: possible duplicate of [simple PHP string replace?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5644947/simple-php-string-replace)

Comment: string replace didn't remove it unfortunately.

Comment: Then you must have used it incorrectly: http://php.net/str_replace

Comment: `$jobs = file_get_contents("api");
$jobs = str_replace("&nbsp;", " ", $jobs); 
$jobs = json_decode($jobs,true);`

Still contains all of the characters

Comment: That works fine: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c7df6456632f8c013ad336b134feb67fe410f091

Answer (score 1):

```
$clean_json = str_replace("&nbsp;", " ", "your json file string");
```

Comment: First thing I tried. Didn't work kept the nbsp in there.