# Get number after string characters

Tags: php, string

I need code for get number after caracters in one string. 
For exmple i have value C1N96 and i whant only 96. Others example: 
if I have string C1N99 must be displayed 99
if I have string C1N1022 must be displayed 1022
I need something that remove "C1N" from result displayed.
thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get first n characters of a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3161816/get-first-n-characters-of-a-string)

Comment: This is pretty much the same question as [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3161816/get-first-n-characters-of-a-string) only you want the last N characters instead of the first.

Comment: possible duplicate of [simple PHP string replace?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5644947/simple-php-string-replace)

Answer (score 3):

If it is only `C1N`, then you can use like this:

```
$main = "C1N983";
$number = str_replace('C1N', '', $main);   // 983
```

or a more greater way use a regular expression like this:

```
<?php
    $text = "C1N384";
    $regex = "/C1N([0-9]+)/";
    preg_match($regex, $text, $matches);
    echo $matches[1];   //384
?>
```

Comment: It really helped great mate

Answer (score 0):

Use [substr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php):

```
$str = "C1N96";    
$str = substr($str, 3);
```