# preg_replace and big brackets {}

Tags: php

I want to make an email template and how to replace everything in the brackets `{}`and with the brackets`{}`?

```
$template = "My name is {NAME}. I'm {AGE} years old.";
$template = preg_replace("{NAME}", "Tom", $template);
$template = preg_replace("{AGE}", "10", $template);
```

and after that should look like this:
**My name is Tom. I'm 10 years old.**

Comment: So, what is not working?

Comment: @u_mulder Test it and you'll see :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Simple PHP string replace?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5644947/simple-php-string-replace)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***You can use `preg_replace()` with single line like below (better than `str_replace()`):-***

```
$template = "My name is {NAME}. I'm {AGE} years old.";
$find = array('/{NAME}/', '/{AGE}/');
$replace = array('TOM', '10');
$template = preg_replace($find, $replace, $template);

echo $template;
```

Output:- https://eval.in/606528

***Note:- it have below benefits:-***

***1***. Single line code to replace all you want. not needed again and again `str_replace()`.

***2***. If some more replacement needed in future then you have to add them into `$find` and `$replace` and that's it. So it is more flexible.

***Sorry i totally forgot to mention that `str_replace()` will also works with array so you can do it like below too:-***

```
<?php

$template = "My name is {NAME}. I'm {AGE} years old.";
$find = array('{NAME}', '{AGE}');
$replace = array('TOM', '10');
$template = str_replace($find, $replace, $template);

echo $template;
```

Output:-https://eval.in/606577

***Note:- Both are equally good. You can go for any one. Thanks***

Comment: What about the escapement? Aren't braces a reserved character in regex?

Comment: @RamenChef  no php regex works in a different way

Comment: I like the way of arrays but it why not replace preg_replace() function with str_replace() it works fine with the arrays? I haven't thought about str_replace before and it seems to be better in my case.

Answer (score 5):

Use `str_replace` instead of `preg_replace`:

```
$template = "My name is {NAME}. I'm {AGE} years old.";
$template = str_replace("{NAME}", "Tom", $template);
$template = str_replace("{AGE}", "10", $template);
```

Answer (score 1):

Regex pattern should have delimiter at start and end of it

```
$template = "My name is {NAME}. I'm {AGE} years old.";
$template = preg_replace("/{NAME}/", "Tom", $template);
echo $template = preg_replace("/{AGE}/", "10", $template);
```

Answer (score 1):

`preg_replace` is not the right function to use in this situation. In this case, the correct option would be `str_replace` or `str_ireplace`. However, for a large amount of data to format, using regex would be a better idea:

```
$associative_formatter_array = array('NAME' => 'Tom', "AGE" => '10');
$template = "My name is {NAME}. I'm {AGE} years old.";
$template = preg_replace_callback("`\{([^\}]*)\}`g", function($match) {
  return $_GLOBALS["associative_formatter_array"][$match[1]];
});
```